# The best/faster way to copy partial array to a range of another array without loop in Java

Tags: java, arrays, copy

Here is the example:

I want to copy the values of `A[p],A[p+1],...A[q]` from `A[0...N]` `(0<=p<=q<=N)` to `B[x],B[x+1],...B[y]` in `B[0...M]` `(0<=x<=y<=M)`, where the size of the copied part are the same, ie, `(q-p)=(y-x)`.

I know I can use for loop, but is there any shorter/quicker/easier function to do that? Or, is there something like, `copy(A,p,q,B,x,y)`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this is faster ( you can assume its no slower then the for loop) but the System class defines a method called arraycopy. You can see the docs here
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
java.lang.System.arraycopy(Object src, int srcPos, Object dest, int destPos, int length)
```

Comment: That's exactly what I want! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in function System.arraycopy() like so:

```
System.arraycopy(A,p,B,x,q-p+1)
```

This basically means "Copy (q-p+1) elements starting from A[p] and place them in B starting from B[x]".

Comment: A and B do not follow java naming standars for array. they should be a and b